# Dynamic Programming Implementation Bug

Tags: algorithm, c++11

So I am working on atcoder's educational DP contest for practice with DP and I am stuck on the first question.

**Problem Statement**

There are N stones, numbered 1,2,…,N. For each i (1 ≤ i≤ N), the height of Stone i is 
), the height of Stone h[i]. There is a frog who is initially on Stone 
1. It will repeat the following action some number of times to reach Stone N:

If the frog is currently on stone i, jump to stone i + 1 or Stone i + 2. Here, a cost of |h[i] - h[j]| is incurred, where j is the stone to land on
Find the minimum possible total cost incurred before the frog reaches Stone 
N.

**My Attempt**

So I used dynamic programming and this is my code

```
// cost[i] is the height of stone i

int solve(int cost[], int N) {
    int dp[N + 1];
    dp[N] = INT_MAX;
    dp[N - 1] = 0;

    for (int i = N - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        dp[i] = min(abs(cost[i] - cost[i + 1]) + dp[i + 1], abs(cost[i] - cost[i + 2]) + dp[i + 2]);
    }

    return dp[0];
}
```

When I test my algorithm on this test case,

```
4
10 30 40 20
```

I keep getting the wrong answer `-2147483599` and sometimes `50`. Can someone point out what is wrong with my algorithm. I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: why you have `cost[i] - cost[i]` in your code?

Comment: That's a typo, I have edited it but I still have the same problem. It doesn't provide the right solution despite the recurrence.

Comment: You set `dp[N]` to `INT_MAX` and then you add to it later. Also, `cost[i + 2]` is out-of-bounds on the first iteration.

Comment: yes, this code has undefined behavior.

Comment: But I start iterating from i = N - 2 to i = 1, so I shouldn't ever be out of bounds.

Comment: @BessieTheCow is right, `cost[i+2]` is out of bounds. `N-2+2` is `N`, but only entries `0` to `N-1` of `cost` are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when `abs(cost[i] - cost[i + 2]) + dp[i + 2]` is executed on the first step, since `dp[i + 1]` is equal to `INT_MAX`, the int type [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and creates a negative value which is then used for incorrect updates in `dp`.

One possible solution is to use `long long dp[N + 1]` instead of `int dp[N + 1]`. Another is to use a smaller initial value for `dp[N]` that would still be big enough to be considered infinitely large.

Answer (score 0):

```
int dp[N + 1];
dp[N] = INT_MAX;
```

make this into:

```
int dp[N+1]={INT_MAX};
```